# Storyboardの使用について

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

素朴な疑問なんですが、Storyboardを使用しないでアプリを記述するメリットは何でしょうか？

Storyboardのみで細部まで表現するのには限界がある事はわかりますが、可能な限り
Storyboardを使用したほうが、視覚的に捉えられ開発にかかる時間も短縮できるのではないかと思います

Storyboardを使用しないでアプリを作った際、どういったいいところ、悪いところがあるのかお聞かせ願いたいです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storyboardを使うときのデメリットがほぼ、Storyboardを使わないメリットになります。

・変更の差分が確認しづらい・動かさないと分からない
・複数人の開発で衝突が発生しやすい（分割することで軽減できる）
・インスタンス化をファイル名やIDなど、文字列でやりとりすることになるので、そのあたりの変更に弱い
・コードで書かないとできないことがある
などです。他にもありますが例として上記があります。

しかし、UIをコードで書くのはどうやっても冗長で、共通化しにくいのでキレイにするのは難しいです。
そのためStoryboardで実現できることはStoryboardを使うと汚くなりがちなUIのコードを無くすことができるので、一般的にはできるだけStoryboardを利用するのが良い方法です。

もちろんStoryboardだけではできないことがあるので、コードを使った方法と、両方を上手に使い分けるのが重要です。

一般的にソフトウェアエンジニアリングにおいて、絶対的な正解があることはほとんどなく、最適解を常に選び続ける、というのがエンジニアの腕の見せどころです。

そのため例えば「Storyboardは一切使わずにコードで書く」というような極端な考え方は、技術の選択肢をただ狭くしているだけなので、たいていは良くないやり方です。

Storyboardを使う方法と、コードで書く方法（あるいはXIBを使う方がいい場面も未だにあります）の両方のメリット・デメリットを理解し、必要に応じて適切に使い分けることが重要です。